# How can I use group_by() then summarise() without ungrouping my data? The df is below

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data.frame:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200),
                                tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
               Type = c("In Store", "In Store", "In Store", "In Store", "In Store", "In Store"),
               Method = c("Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie"), 
               `Category Full` = c("SAFES", "WOOD PELLETS", "FEEDLOT PANELS", "S&H OR HOME DELIVERY", "T-POSTS", "S&H OR HOME DELIVERY" ), 
               Week = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My code is this:

```
res02 <- d %>%
select(Date, Method, Category_Full ='Category Full') %>%
mutate(Week = week(Date)) %>%
group_by(Week, Category_Full) %>%
mutate(Category_Count = nchar(Category_Full))
```

[image]

I am trying to find the top 5 `$Category_Full` base on `$Method` for each Week of the year. The Week Column lists 1:52. I tried using `nchar` and `summarise` but I can't get this to work

The Excel sheet would be similar end result

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use summarize?

Comment: When I used summarise, it automatically ungroups() my dataframe

Comment: Your description is not clear to me. What is your desired output? It would be helpful if you could provide us with a reproducible [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions. You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for some great advice.)

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200, 
1609027200, 1609027200, 1609027200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Type = c("In Store", "In Store", "In Store", "In Store", 
"In Store", "In Store"), Method = c("Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie", 
"Roadie", "Roadie", "Roadie"), `Category Full` = c("SAFES", "WOOD PELLETS", 
"FEEDLOT PANELS", "S&H OR HOME DELIVERY", "T-POSTS", "S&H OR HOME DELIVERY"
), Week = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Trying to group_by() Type and Method, then find the top Category in those groups for every week of the year. Looking at trends of items that I sell.

Comment: Please edit your question with reproducible data. Do not place it in the comments because it cannot be properly formatted there. The `summarize()` function has a `.groups=` parameter. You can use `.groups="keep"` not to drop groups.